# php isset on a protected array returns false, but isset on one of its keys returns true

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to analyse a curious case where some code regarding isset() behaves differently on my local Windows machine (PHP 7.0.3) from our Unix test server (recently updated to PHP 7.0.6). But when trying to create a simpler reproducible code snippet on the Windows machine, it behaves like the Unix server.

The line in question is

```
if (isset($this->settings[$Model->alias]['Log']->_schema['model'])) {
```

`$this->settings[$Model->alias]['Log']` is an object, `_schema`is a protected property, which is an array. The key `model`exists in this array. On the Unix server, the if-condition returns false. On the windows server it returns true. On the Unix test server before the update, as well as on our productive web server, it also returns true.

I understand that `isset()`, performed on a protected property, should always return false. So it shouldn't have worked in the first place. Checking on the property itself indeed returns always false, both on Windows and on Unix:

`$this->settings[$Model->alias]['Log']->_schema) // false`

But checking for a key of this array property behaves differently. On Windows and the productive server:

`$this->settings[$Model->alias]['Log']->_schema['model']) // true`

On the test server:

`$this->settings[$Model->alias]['Log']->_schema['model']) // false`

I then tried to create a simpler reproducible code snippet:

```
<?php
class Log {
    protected $_schema = array(
        'model' => array(
            'name' => 'change',
        ),
    );
}

class Model {
    public $alias = 'Contact';
}

class LogableBehavior {
    public $settings = array();

    function __construct() {
        $Model = new Model();

        $this->settings[$Model->alias]['Log'] = new Log();

        echo isset($this->settings[$Model->alias]['Log']->_schema)?'true':'false';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo isset($this->settings[$Model->alias]['Log']->_schema['model'])?'true':'false';
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}

$obj = new LogableBehavior();
```

This outputs

```
false
false
```

on all machines. This is what I would expect. But within the bigger project code `isset($this->settings[$Model->alias]['Log']->_schema['model'])` returns true, on my local Windows machine and the productive server.

I read in other places that when using `isset()` while checking for an array key, but the variable in question is actually a string instead of an array, the results can be unexpected. But this should not apply here, because the protected property `_schema` is an array when I debug it.

Any ideas for an explanation?

Comment: Can the problem be reproduced by an unit test? Also did you try if you can replicate the problem in a very basic php script to see if this is a problem of php in general or if it is specific to your code and the framework? Also the way you use the models for logging seems... strange. Take a look at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html and implement a DB log engine? Not sure what exactly you want but I think this can be done better.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So far I was not able to reproduce this with a basic php script (that's what I tried to achieve with the "simpler reproducible code snippet").We implemented DB logging with an adaption of Alexander Morland's LogableBehavior. The original uses a similar construct (isset() performed on the protected property "_schema")

Comment: I believe Your Log model in production is extending `Model` class, which overrides getter (`__get()`) for properties.